# Hint for solving $ y (y')^2 + (x-y) y' - x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Need to solve the following ODE:

$$ y (y')^2 + (x-y) y' - x = 0$$

I don't really know how to start. Any hints?

Comment: I'm assuming $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: @Myridium that's right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ y (y')^2 + (x-y) y' - x = 0$$
You can factor 
$$ y (y')^2 + (x-y) y' - x= (yy'+x)(y'-1)$$
Hence you can solve separately the two equations
$$y'=1\qquad \mbox{or}\qquad y'=-\frac{x}{y}$$

Comment: How does one get to the bottom line? And some explanation of how you knew to use this technique might be appropriate.

Comment: I simply solved the first equation in $y'$ as a 2nd order equation.

Comment: @Myridium Dario recognized that, after all, this is simply a quadratic equation, and prompted the quadratic formula